# Equivalent of AudioManager.AudioPlaybackCallback in older Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am building an app for volume control.

One of the things that would be real useful is knowing when there has been a change in the playback state.

Android Oreo has the class `AudioManager.AudioPlaybackCallback` which can be instantiated and registered to receive notifications.

Is there any equivalent or similar class or interface in older versions?